Fast (relatively) execution time, but slow response time of a GCP Cloud Run function
The Setup
I have two Python GCP Cloud Run Gen2 functions. One is an orchestrator function that receives the initial http request, breaks up the request into smaller chunks and invokes the second function for each of the chunks (15 chunks for each request resulting in 15 requests to the second function for each 1 request to the orchestrator). Each instance of the second function is responsible for downloading and processing a file of around 250-400MB, resulting in a response of 100-300KB.
The reason for this architecture is that network bandwidth is limited on a per-instance basis, therefore downloading all 15 files concurrently from one instance is considerably slower, hence the delegation of downloads to multiple instances of a separate function.
The orchestrator function has 1/6 cpu, 512MB memory and a concurrency of 1. The download & process function has 1 cpu, 1GB memory and a concurrency of 1. Both functions sit in us-central1. The functions are written and deployed using the firebase wrapper for google cloud functions.
The Issue
According to logs from the Cloud Console, each instance of the download & process usually completes its tasks in anywhere between 5-20 seconds.

However, on the receiving end in the orchestrator function, which made those requests to the download & process function, I am seeing those same requests logged as often taking 1.5-2 times as long.

Seeing how I am making only 15 requests, I would expect there not to be such a large discrepancy between the supposed response times that are logged within the download & process function (plus some leeway for the round trip) and the actual response times.
The considerations
On the orchestrator function my cpu usage sits at 10-25% and memory utilization at ~40%.

On the download & process function my cpu usage sits at 50-55% and memory utilization at 45-100%. I know 100% sounds rough and could be an issue someone could point at as being the cause - I want to warn you that the unexpected behavior described in the section above happens consistently even with requests that only utilize 50% of memory allocation.

As evident by the logs within the download & process function, all 15 requests arrive at virtually the same time, so the issue is not the orchestrator function throttling sending of those requests.
What I have tried
Bumping resources
I have tried doubling, quadrupling and octupling resources available to instances of each of the functions and did not see any improvements in regards to the issue described.
Refactoring my code
I am using Python's asyncio and aiohttp to make the concurrent requests from the orchestrator function to the download & process function. I have tried different setups of making those requests: one ClientSession for all of the requests (1 client session in total), one ClientSession for each of the requests (15 client session in total) and one ClientSession for each 3 requests (5 client sessions in total). No approach has provided a significant benefit over any of the other ones. Currently I am using the 5 total client session setup.
I have also tried increasing the read_bufsize of each ClientSession from the default 64KB to 512KB and 1MB so that the client sessions can read the response body in one go. I am able to do so because memory of the orchestrator function is not a bottleneck since it is only seeing a usage of ~40%.
Optimizing response sizes
Initially, the process & download function would send responses in JSON. These responses would be 3-4 times the size of the responses the process & download function sends right now. This was achieved by two efforts. First - optimizing the data sent in the responses - using ints instead of floats, which cut down the response sizes by a factor of 1.2-1.5. Second - switching from JSON to Protobuf, which cut down the response sizes by a factor of 2-3 further.
Using other languages
I have tried rewriting the orchestrator function in two languages. First - in Rust that was compiled to Python bindings - which did not help. Second - in pure Golang, to see if perhaps the issue lied with Python's performance - still did not help.
Testing locally
I have tried testing the orchestrator function locally, meaning the instance would be sitting on my machine making requests to the download & process function sitting in the google cloud. This setup has shown the same issue, which makes me want to rule out the cause being slow ingestion of responses by the orchestrator function instance on the cloud, since whatever resource or bandwidth limitations it would have had on the cloud, would not be the same on my local machine.
Conclusion
I am at a defeat with this issue and have no ideas on how to trace it further. Due to all the things I have tried, I am currently leaning to suspecting that this may be some peculiarity of how GCP Cloud Run Functions send responses after the instances process them? Perhaps there is some sort of queue that throttles sending the responses from the 15 instances and that is why I am seeing the first requests' responses come as expected and then some come with the aforementioned delay?
Any input would be greatly appreciated as I am grasping at straws at the moment.

Can you share the code of your orchestrator? Or answer this question: When you receive a request, on the orchestrator, you are performing a loop to call, in async mode, 15 times the processing function. At the end of this loop, are you waiting for the async call response, or do you send the response to the requester immediately?

@guillaumeblaquiere Orchestrator is quite a lengthy function with all sorts of other validations before and after receiving the responses of the processing functions, so I won't share the whole code. I am not totally sure if I understand your question correctly. In the orchestrator, in a loop, I am creating 15 asyncio.ensure_future tasks and putting all of them into an array. After that I await the responses of those tasks with asyncio.gather(*tasks_array). After that, I compile all of the responses into one and send the result back to the requester of the orchestrator function.

I do not use Python, BUT...
Cloud Run instances do have to be initialized before they actually run... once run, they can stay in active memory for "some time", and do not need this initialization.  However, in your case, each of the instances has to be "spun up" to run.  Many of my functions take longer to "spin up" than they do to run.
There are a couple of options: there are settings to keep a minimum number of instances already initialized.  This comes at the cost of long-running instances, that you do have to pay for.  Also you have to decide how many to keep running, because overlapping sessions can easily go beyond whatever number you set.
Another trick I have used is implement a sort of "null function call" for the instances.  That way running one instance can immediately make a call to another, which uses the "null function call" to avoid an infinite loop of calls - but does keep at least one more instance in memory than is in use...
I put in a feature request some time ago, suggesting a setting of "minimum number of running sessions beyond the active set" - so you actively have "spares" around, scaling with usage.  No implementation yet that I've seen.
Net: instance initiation is often the slowest part, and you have to decide on a way to keep some number of instances ready to respond OR tolerate the delays.

First of all, thank you for reading my post, I know it's quite a lengthy one. I appreciate your help.
Onto the topic, if I understand correctly, you are suggesting that the discrepancy between the response time displayed in the logs of the download & process function and the actual response time logged in the orchestrator function comes from cold starts of the instances of the download & process function?
It was my assumption that the logs within the download & process function would include the container startup time in the "execution time" logged on each response. Am I wrong?

It is not my experience that startup time  is included - the logs I've seen start when the instance is loaded.  That being said, it is possible to turn on the needed information on the google console logs... the entries look something like "initialize" and "start"

I am going to be honest - my attempts at finding instance start up time logs associated with execution logs failed. Likely a skill issue, but I have poked around on my own and researched online to no avail, so there is a chance its not possible. However, I did test making the 15 requests to a function that has no warm instances and still got the same behavior, where some requests responded at or around their execution time and some did have a significant delay, so I think that should rule out cold starts, unless they are that much inconsistent.

I have resolved the issue by migrating the download & process function from Python Rust bindings deployed on GCP to pure Rust deployed on AWS. The behavior described in my initial post has vanished after that change. In addition to that, the cost of the download & process function reduced significantly as it needed less resources with pure Rust. This has prompted me to rewrite the orchestrator and all other Python functions in Golang, improving cold starts, reducing resource usage, increasing speed and reducing cost all across my infrastructure. Python was just a bad choice for cloud functions

I will mention that cold start times are inconsistent - mostly because Google keeps them "warm" for an inconsistent amount of time.  As far as I'm concerned, Python has only one "virtue" - easy to read, easy to write.

Yes, instances stay "warm" for inconsistent periods of time. However, there are graphs showing how many instances are "warm" at a point in time. The function I had tested was stale for 3+ days and showed 0 active instances, therefore my expectation would be for the cold starts to be consistent. As for Python, you nailed it on the head, although I would say the data science ecosystem built for Python could also be added to the list of its virtues. I appreciate your time helping me out!
